# Would a simliar "freshness" question about onions be considered a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I recently asked [this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/54151/how-do-i-preserve-a-tomatos-freshness-after-it-is-cut) about how to keep a Tomato fresh, with the understanding that keeping it in the fridge would cause wilting, and that keeping it on the counter could lead to bacteria and other issues. I've gotten some good answers and it's been a well-recieved question.

Now I have a similar question about an equally difficult to preserve food - onions.  They absorb flavor readily, which makes it extremely difficult to store an onion after it's been cut.  So I'd like to know how best to store it.

The problem is...I can see a lot of the answers I got for the tomato question being re-stated for the onion question - to use it on the same day, to use special containers, et cetera.  And I'm afraid that a question so similar to my tomato question right after it would be seen as a duplicate question.

Would such a question, so shortly after asking about tomatoes, be different enough to distinguish itself as an independent question?

Answer (score 4):

Asking about keeping onions would not be a duplicate of the tomato question. There are questions on the site though regarding onions that may be a duplicate.